# NPM fails to install packages in the theme directory when running npm i

Tags: bigcommerce, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

When I attempt to install the stencil untils module by running `npm i` in a theme directory I get the following error message.

```
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @bigcommerce/stencil-cli@2.1.1: wanted: {"node":">= 10.0.0 <11.0.0"} (current: {"node":"12.22.7","npm":"6.14.15"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @bigcommerce/stencil-cli@2.1.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for upath@0.1.7: wanted: {"node":">=0.10 <=5"} (current: {"node":"12.22.7","npm":"6.14.15"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: upath@0.1.7

npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/bigcommerce-labs/node-sass.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! github.com[0: 20.248.137.48]: errno=Operation timed out
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

I'm using node 12.22, npm 6.14.15, and stencil 4.0.0. I've also tried with node 14 and stencil 5.0.0, and reinstalling the stencil cli.

Appreciate any ideas people might have on how to resolve this.

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `@bigcommerce/stencil-cli` is set to 2.1.1 within the package.json file. If it is, you'll likely need to update that there.